# AudioFileReadPackets Error -50

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I'm playing with Audio API and my first step was to read the content of a file into the buffer.
I have the following code, but when `AudioFileReadPackets` is executed I get return code -50 which I don't get it, since in the documentation it doesn't exists.
Can you please point me to the right direction? Any idea will be appreciated!

```
    //create url for file
    CFURLRef myFileURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, INPUT_FILE, NULL);
    AudioFileID audioFile;
    OSStatus error;

    error = AudioFileOpenURL(myFileURL,kAudioFileReadPermission,0,&audioFile);
    CFRelease(myFileURL);

    if(error != noErr) {
        printf("%d",(int)error);
        exit(1);
    }

    AudioStreamBasicDescription  dataFormat;
    UInt32 size = sizeof(dataFormat);

    error = AudioFileGetProperty(audioFile, kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat, &size, &dataFormat);

    if(error != noErr) {
        printf("%d",(int)error);
        exit(1);
    }

    UInt32 dataSize;
    error = AudioFileGetPropertyInfo(audioFile, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataPacketCount, &dataSize, NULL);

    if(error != noErr) {
        printf("%d",(int)error);
        exit(1);
    }

    UInt32 packetCount;
    error = AudioFileGetProperty(audioFile, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataPacketCount, &dataSize, &packetCount);

    if(error != noErr) {
        printf("%d",(int)error);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("File opened, packet count: %d\n", packetCount);
    UInt32 packetsRead = packetCount;
    UInt32 bytesRead = 0;

    if(packetCount > 0) {
        SInt16 audioData = *(SInt16 *)malloc(2 * packetCount);
        error = AudioFileReadPackets(audioFile, false, &bytesRead, NULL, 0, &packetsRead, audioData);

        if(error != noErr) {
            printf("%d",(int)error);
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Read %d bytes, %d packets",bytesRead,packetsRead);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-50 = paramErr means you passed an incorrect parameter. Documentation says that the fourth parameter for AudioFileReadPackets must only be NULL for constant bitrate audio.

Comment: thank you for your answer, you provided me exactly what I needed! I will have a look on how I can solve the issue.